# SQL how to join two different tables columns as result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

table1:

```
---------------------------
|id_column1 | name_column |
---------------------------
|        1  | my_name1    |
|        2  | my_name2    |
---------------------------
```

table2:

```
--------------------------------------
|id_column2 | surname_column | fk_id1|
--------------------------------------
|      111  | my_surname1    | 1     |
|      222  | my_surname2    | 2     |
--------------------------------------
fk_id1 is foreign key referenced to table1.id_column1

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE fk_id1=1;

--------------------------------------
|id_column2 | surname_column | fk_id1|
--------------------------------------
|      111  | my_surname1    | 1     |
```

How can I get this (is it possible at all to join two table columns as result):

```
------------------------------------------------
|id_column2 | surname_column | fk_id1| name    |
------------------------------------------------
|      111  | my_surname1    | 1     |my_name1 |
```

Something like below:

```
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE fk_id1=1 AND SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id_column1=1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.name_column 
FROM table2 t2 
     INNER JOIN table1 t1 on t2.fk_id1 = id_column1 
WHERE t1.id_column1 = 1
```

Here's a sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bc00/1) for testing.

Comment: what does t2 and t1 stand for? Are they alias of table1 and table2?

Comment: @torayeff That's exactly what they are!

Comment: @XaviLópez  the example doesn't contain any foreign key variable. This looks similar to sql joins

Comment: @PSivachandran the OP stated there was a FK, but didn't specify primary key or unique constraints in `table1`. I've updated the fiddle with PK/FK.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT id_column2,surname_column,fk_id1,name_column FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.id_column1=table2.fk_id1 AND table1.id_column1=1;
```

Comment: +1 now. It had syntax issues [before the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14643053/2).

Comment: @XaviLópez, yes i did, changed it when I saw it. Fast typing :)

Answer (score 1):

This is simple.Can be done using the inner Join.

```
SELECT id_column2,surname_column,fk_id1,name_column as name FROM table1 Inner Join table2 on table1.id_column1=table2.fk_id1 where table1.id_column1=1;
```

Or

```
SELECT id_column2,surname_column,fk_id1,name_column as name FROM table1 , table2 where table1.id_column1=table2.fk_id1 and table1.id_column1=1;
```

If you want result in the below format:

```
------------------------------------------------
|id_column2 | surname_column | fk_id1| name    |
------------------------------------------------
|      111  | my_surname1    | 1     |my_name1 |
```